# Magento 2 API integrating in Wordpress with plugin

Tags: php, magento

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin which checks if an item is added in a Magento v2 Webshop and get the information from that item and insert it into Wordpress.

I'm making a PHP class and bumped into some trouble, which I've been staring at myself. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

First, I made integration in Magento V2 and used the API keys in my Wordpress plugin.

The class I made which handles the API calls and returns data.

```
class MagentoIntegration {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param array $keys   Contains Access and Consumers keys
     * @param array $config Contains URL, Wordpress options
     */
    function __construct($keys, $config)
    {

        $this->keys             = (object) $keys;
        $this->config           = (object) $config;

        $this->user             = $this->keys->username;
        $this->password         = $this->keys->password;

        $this->url              = $this->config->url;

        $this->credentials      = array("username" => $this->user, "password" => $this->password);
        $this->signature        = array();

    }

    /**
     * Get Magento v2 Access Token
     * @return string Returns the requested Access Token
     */
    public function getToken() {
        $this->token = $this->cUrlRequest($this->url . '/rest/V1/integration/admin/token', null, 'POST');

        return json_decode($this->token);
    }

    /**
     * Gets and returns all products
     * @param  string $token Access Token
     * @return array         Returns all products
     */
    public function getAllProducts($token) {

        $this->products = $this->cUrlRequest($this->url . '/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=', $token);

        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all categories
     * @param  string $token Access Token
     * @return array         Returns all categories
     */
    public function getAllCategories($token) {

        $this->categories = $this->cUrlRequest($this->url . '/rest/V1/categories', $token);

        return $this->categories;

    }

    /**
     * Handles the request using cUrl
     * @param  string $url    Magento v2 API url
     * @param  string $token  Access Token
     * @param  string $method Method (GET, POST) default: GET
     * @return array          Result
     */
    private function cUrlRequest($url, $token = null, $method = 'GET') {

        $this->url          = $url;
        $this->method       = $method;
        $this->token        = $token;

        $this->signature  = json_encode($this->credentials);

        $curlConfig   = array(
                            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $this->method,
                            CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,          
                        );

         if(!$this->token) { // Only if $token is requested do this
             $curlConfig[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $this->signature;
             $curlConfig[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($this->signature));
        } else {
            $curlConfig[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->token);

        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Here I make a few calls to the Class

```
<?php

$keys = array(/* contains access and consumer keys, login information */);

$config = array(/* contains config like baseurl */);

$magento    = new MagentoIntegration($keys, $config);

$token      = $magento->getToken();

$products   = $magento->getAllProducts($token);
$categories = $magento->getAllCategories($token);

echo $products;
echo $categories;
```

The `$token` variable gets a token, so that works.

The variables `$products` and `$categories` both return `{"message":"Request does not match any route."}`.

My question is where I go wrong? Why doesn't it match a route?

Comment: i do not sure but maybe in  get category method  you need to set parent category id /categories/:cat_id
and for get products you are send token in search parameters  i think it's not right, check this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html